# The convergence of $ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p(n)}$ when p(n) is a polynomial of degree bigger than 1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I prove the convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p(n)}$, I know the bigger term is going to dominate and since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converge then also the first sum however I dont know how can i bounded correctly.

Any Hints!

Comment: If $d$ is the degree of the polynomial, use limit comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n^d}.$

Comment: I didn't know this method, thats make really easy this problem thanks.

Comment: $\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}^+,p(n)\neq 0$ is required to make the series make sense.

Comment: It is not really clear what the question is asking.  Is $p(n)$ an arbitrary polynomial of degree $n$ or is it an arbitrary polynomial evaluate at $n$?  Are you wanting to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p(n)}$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p(i)}$? Clearly the person who wrote their answer below wouldn't have to say "I assume that you are asking..." if it was 100% clear what you were asking.  Please clarify, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you are asking about the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{p(n)}$ where $p$ is a polynomial whose degree $d$ is greater than $1$. Let's write
$$
p(n) = a_dn^d + a_{d-1}n^{d-1} + \dotsb + a_1n + a_0,
$$
where $a_d \ne 0$. Choose $N$ so large that $|a_{d-1}n^{d-1} + \dots + a_1n + a_0| < {|a_{d}n^d|\over 2}$ for all $n>N$. (I will let you think about why such a choice of $N$ is possible by considering the degree of $a_{d-1}n^{d-1} + \dots + a_1n + a_0$ and the degree of $a_dn^d$.)

With this choice of $N$, and an application of the reverse triangle inequality,
$$
\sum_{n>N}\frac{1}{|p(n)|} \le \sum_{n>N}\frac{2}{|a_dn^d|} = {2\over|a_d|}\sum_{n>N}\frac{1}{n^d}.
$$
Now, the series $\sum_{n>N}\frac{1}{n^d}$ converges because $d > 1$, by the $p$-test, so the original series converges absolutely.

Comment: If $x< y$ then $\frac{1}{y} < \frac{1}{x}$ however you are instead writing 
$\frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{y}$ (first inequality in the 2nd centered equation)

Comment: @Squirtle: It seems you may be under the impression that I am writing $|p(n)| \le |a_dn^d|/2 \implies 1/|p(n)| \le 2/|a_dn^d|$, which is indeed incorrect. However, I am not claiming that $|p(n)| \le |a_dn^d|/2$, and there is not actually any error. I am writing $|p(n)| = |p(n) + L(n)|$, where $L(n) = a_{d-1}n^{d-1}+\dots+a_1n+a_0$, and applying the reverse triangle inequality: $|p(n)| \ge |a_dn^d|-|L(n)|$. Then I use the fact that $|L(n)|<|a_dn^d|/2$ for $n>N$ to get what I have shown.

Comment: Changed my downvote to an upvote.  Thank you for clarifying, it seemed like an important detail and in its absence I was fixated on a fallacious inference that you didn't even make.  Thank you!

Comment: @Squirtle: Happy to clarify :-)